# TextAlignment on TextView for Rtl and Ltr text

Tags: android, textview, text-alignment

How do TextView decides to align text left or right?

If you want to align a piece of text, you should apply AlignmentSpan which should be one of these 3 values(NORMAL, OPPOSITE, CENTER).

If you set alignment to NORMAL depends on what is first character it decides to align text left or right.

Below are some examples of text and alignment:

Hi               : Left

@Hi              : Left

سلام              : Right

@سلام             : Right

*@ Hi            : Left

*@ سلام           : Right

Hi سلام           : Left

سلام Hi           : Right

I wanna know how exactly textView determines text alignment?
If possible please give a regex pattern to determine text alignment.

I want something like this:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(patternString);
if(regex.matcher(text).matches()) {
    // now text will be left aligned
}
```

I wanna find out patternString value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the algorithm decides based the on first letter-based character of the text (i.e. it finds the non-symbolic character and check if it is an RTL character or not).

You can use `\p{L}` or `\p{Letter}` in RegEx to find the first match, then compare its first character with the range of RTL unicode characters:

```
boolean isRtl(String str) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^\\p{L}]*)(\\p{L})(.*)";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    if (m.matches()) {
      String firstMatch = m.group(2);
      char c = firstMatch.charAt(0);
      return c >= 0x590 && c <= 0x6ff;
    }
    return false;
}
```